# WooCommerce maximum number of products of a certain category in cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, limit, product

How can I set a limit to the number of products in the cart of the same category? 
Can this also be done with products with for instance the same price?

Thank you very much in advance.

```
function wpbo_minimum_item_quantity_validation( $passed, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variations ) {
    // Make $woocommerce accessible
    global $woocommerce;

    // Set a minimum item quantity
    $minimum = 10; 

    // Check if the quantity is smaller than our minimum value
    if ( $quantity < $minimum ) {

        // Get the product title for the error statement
        $product = get_product( $product_id );
        $product_title = $product->post->post_title;

        // Add the error
        $woocommerce->add_error( sprintf( "You must add a minimum of %s %s's to your cart to proceed." , $minimum, $product_title ) );

    // If the quantity is 10 or above return true
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? I would be interested to see your attempt at a solution. First place I would look is the hooks WC uses to add an item to the cart.

Comment: @Cloud_Ratha I already have the code above. But I don't know how to modify it so that I can set a maximum to the categories.